# Get all works' title from artist in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

So here's what i want to get:
For each artist in the table, I want it to post it's name and the last three works he made.

Here's what i have so far:

```
    class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :image, :name

      has_many :works

    end


    class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :artist_id, :exhibition_id, :image, :title

      belongs_to :artist
      belongs_to :exhibition

    end

<% @artists.each do |artist| %>
<div class="one-artist">

    <h3><%= artist.name %></h3>

    <div class="artist-work first-work">
        <%= artist.works.title %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

I thought this would be an acceptable way to approach the artists works, but it seems to fail.

It gives me the following repsonse:

```
undefined method `title' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000102e89038>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works is a relation that contains all of the works. if you want to access, say, the first you should write something like `artist.works.first.title`

Comment: Thanks, I see your point, but I can't figure out the solution. How can i reach only one work?

Comment: you should either iterate over all of the works using each, or, if you want only the first, use the code I wrote above: artist.works.first.title

Answer (score 1):

```
<% artist.works.each do |work| %>
    <div class="artist-work">  
        <%= work.title %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```